# Get array of referenced ids in Doctrine ODM

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I have a Company class that references users:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document()
 */
class Company {

    /* ... */

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Topboard\UserBundle\Document\User", inversedBy="companies")
     */
    protected $users;
}
```

In my controller I need to check if the reference to the user exists in the company and keep only the reference to that user, not other references. I also want to avoid multiple DB requests for users. I just want to check if the id of the references matches `$currentUserId`.

```
public function getCompanyAction($companyId, $currentUserId) {
    $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
    $company = $dm->getRepository( 'TopboardAppBundle:Company' )->findOneById( $companyId );

    foreach ($company->getUsers() as $user) {
        // Foreach will query each user separetly. This is not what I need.
        // I need somehow access array of references' ids
        // and compare them with the $currentUserId
        if($user->getId() !== $currentUserId){
            // Remove reference
        }        
    }

    return $company;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon investigation it turned out that the query is fired when collection is initialized to avoid one query per document later (for reasoning why we can't do better yet see [this comment on GH](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/1452#issuecomment-234283457)). The case is not lost though, solution is not anywhere near being beautiful, but sometimes OD/RMs requires these when performance needs to come first:

```
$users = $company->getUsers();
// condition below assumes $company is loaded from db so $users is in fact instance of PersistentCollection(Interface)
if ($users->isInitialized()) {
   $ids = $users->map(function($user) { 
       return $user->getId(); 
   })->toArray();
} else {
   $ids = array_map(function($dbRef) { 
        /* this depends on reference type */ 
        return (string) $dbRef['$id']; 
   }, $users->getMongoData());
}
```

You could also just place your logic in places where I'm mapping collections to get list of ids of referenced users.

**Original answer that is relevant for single references or unitinitailzed proxies**

If object is not loaded yet (i.e. it is still uninitialized `Proxy`) then asking for that document's identifier will not trigger additional queries, here is snippet of a `Proxy` class generated by ODM in my project:

```
public function getId()
{
    if ($this->__isInitialized__ === false) {
        return  parent::getId();
    }


    $this->__initializer__ && $this->__initializer__->__invoke($this, 'getId', []);

    return parent::getId();
}
```

Also to expand answer a bit, you can prevent n+1 problem with [priming](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/priming-references.html), this way ODM will fetch all referenced documents in one query.

Comment: Proxy sounds about right. So you suggest to change the id getter in the User class? I think the issue is that when I do `foreach`, it already triggers a DB request.

Comment: No, your getter should remain intact, you can check autogenerated Proxy class (they're usually in `app/cache/lcl/doctrine/odm/mongodb/Proxies/`). As for `foreach`, it shouldn't trigger query on its own since your reference is the owning side thus already available in the document after initial fetch.

Comment: What I mean is, your code looks correct and shouldn't trigger any additional queries at this point

Comment: So `$company->getUsers()` should not trigger the db query? It does for me atm.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in ODM then, would you mind creating a failing test case and submitting it as a pull request?